# Stacky proof of no elliptic curves over Z

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, moduli-spaces, algebraic-stacks

It is a well known result that there are no Elliptic curves over the integers with every where good reduction. In fact this is even true for abelian varieties (and hence higher genus curves) but let me restrict my question to elliptic curves.

In terms of the moduli stack $M_{1,1} 
$ of elliptic curves over the integers, this says that the stack has no integral sections.

Since $M_{1,1}$ is relatively uncomplicated as a stack (it is essentially the affine line with a few stacky points) , perhaps it is possible to find a direct proof of this result? Is such a proof known?

I expect the ramification arguments in the standard proof should correspond to some non trivial obstructions at the stacky points.

Comment: The stack $\mathcal M_{1,1}$ is not so simple at the (crucial) primes $2$ and $3$, so I'm not so sure a stacky proof would be nice.

Comment: I just came in to say what I see Will already said!

Comment: Ah, the word "essentially," bane of our lives.

Comment: Exercise: what *are* the Spec Z points of the weighted projective line P(4,6) with one point removed, which is what M_{1,1} would be if it weren't for those two little meddling primes?

Comment: @JSE by the universal property of weighted projective space, to get a integral point, I would have to give a line bundle on Z and 2 sections in its 4th and 6th power the don't simultaneously vanish at any prime. Since all line bundles are trivial, the powers don't do anything and this is the same as an integral point which is to say, 2 coprime integers. Do I have that right?